# Receiving error: html-pdf: PDF generation timeout. Phantom.js script did not exit. within Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, phantomjs, node-html-pdf

I'm building out a firebase function that uses the html-pdf package (which uses PhantomJS).  The function works fine on my local machine, but whenever I deploy the function on Firebase, I get the following error:

> Error: html-pdf: PDF generation timeout. Phantom.js script did not exit.

I've changed the timeout parameter for `pdf.create()` and keep getting the same result.  Any idea on what might be creating this issue that is unique to only when a deploy this to Firebase?  Code is below.

```js
const pdf = require('html-pdf');
const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 540,  // in seconds
    memory: '2GB'
  }

exports.sendToKindle = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
   // REMOVED A BLOCK OF CODE FOR SIMPLICITY, BUT CAN PUT BACK IN IF NEEDED//
   var options = { 
       format: 'Letter',
       directory: "/tmp", 
       timeout: 540000,  // in milliseconds
   };
    
   const blookFileName = createFileName(blookData.title) + '.pdf';
    
   const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), `${blookFileName}`);

   const htmlFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'book.html');

   const htmlFs = fs.openSync(htmlFilePath, 'w');

   await fs.promises.appendFile(htmlFilePath, bookHTML);

   const fd = fs.openSync(tempFilePath, 'w');

   var html = fs.readFileSync(htmlFilePath, 'utf8');

   let mailgunObject = null;

   pdf.create(html, options).toFile(tempFilePath, async (err, res) => {
           if (err) return console.error(err);
           mailgunObject = await sendEmail(tempFilePath, kindleEmail);
           return console.log(res);
       });

   fs.closeSync(fd);
   fs.closeSync(htmlFs);

   return cors(req, res, () => {
        res.status(200).type('application/json').send({'response': 'Success'})
    })
```

Comment: Your code is not waiting for `create().toFile()` to complete.  It's almost certainly asynchronous, given that it accepts a callback.

Comment: @DougStevenson, wouldn't that issue then also be reflected on the local firebase emulator as well?  This is only an issue when I deploy it to firebase.

Comment: No, the emulator will not shut down the request the moment it returns.  It is not a 100% accurate emulation.

Comment: @DougStevenson, okay that makes sense.  What' s the best way to address that?  I can't have the ```return cors(req, res, () => {
        res.status(200).type('application/json').send({'response': 'Success'})
    })``` within the callback.

Comment: Return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.  That's how you tell Cloud Functions that it's safe to clean up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by modifying the code by having the pdf.create().toFile() placed within the return of the cloud function.

```js
const pdf = require('html-pdf');
const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 300,  // in seconds
    memory: '1GB'
  }

exports.sendToKindle = functions.runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
   // REMOVED A BLOCK OF CODE FOR SIMPLICITY, BUT CAN PUT BACK IN IF NEEDED//
   var options = { 
       format: 'Letter',
       directory: "/tmp", 
       timeout: 540000,  // in milliseconds
   };
    
   const blookFileName = createFileName(blookData.title) + '.pdf';
    
   const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), `${blookFileName}`);

   const htmlFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'book.html');

   const htmlFs = fs.openSync(htmlFilePath, 'w');

   await fs.promises.appendFile(htmlFilePath, bookHTML);

   const fd = fs.openSync(tempFilePath, 'w');

   var html = fs.readFileSync(htmlFilePath, 'utf8');

   return cors(req, res, () => {
        pdf.create(html, options).toFile(tempFilePath, async (err, res) => {
           if (err) return console.error(err);
           let mailgunObject = await sendEmail(tempFilePath, kindleEmail);
           fs.closeSync(fd);
           fs.closeSync(htmlFs);
           return console.log(res);
        });

        res.status(200).type('application/json').send({'response': 'Success'})
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Actualy I realized that when I called the function using html-pdf through Postman, or simply through a request by Google Chrome, the pdf used to generate within a 2 or 3 seconds, whereas it was more 2 or 3 minutes when calling it directly from my app.
So this is what I did : putting html-pdf in a separate function that I deployed, and then calling it :

```
https = require('https'); 
https.get(https://us-central1-your-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/your-function-using-html-pdf)
```